# Android viewpager recyclerview update after dialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have an app where consisting of a viewpager with 3 tabs, with the second tab containing a recyclerview with items.

If I were to hold onto the item, a dialogfragment would popup. There's an option to delete the item from the database. However, I'm having trouble working out how I would refresh the recyclerview. I've tried creating a new fragment (2nd tab fragment), however, the data doesn't update.

The only thing I can get working is by recreating a new activity, however, that loads the first tab of the viewpager.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: u can use recyclerview adapter so simple when you remove item at that place you can clear your adapter and again fill your data into your adapter. so easliy your recyclerview can  refersh and item can removed .

Comment: @Kishan how do I call the adapter methods in the dialog after the dialog is dismissed?

Comment: can you post your code